# Desire password-required login for Facebook on Android

Tags: security, facebook

I would like the security of mandatory password login to Facebook from my phone.  How to do this on Samsung Galaxy Express?

Comment: I don't see a setting within the app. I think you'll need to manually log out.

Answer (score 0):

As AlEverett has stated, there is not a setting within the app to do this. Though you could download the free app called [App Lock](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.domobile.applock) and set a password that way on whatever apps that you'd like.